# What is the procedure to become a Cricket Umpire?

Tags: cricket, officiating

In cricket how does someone become an umpire at international level? Is there some procedure for this? How are they selected and what is the criteria for this?

Comment: 1000+ views and only one upvote. Plus one downvote as well. This is very interesting. Looks like normal people are looking for these kind of questions and the members here do not want these type of questions.

Comment: I am Gautamkumar Soni now a days doing umpirig from GUJARAT STATE I was following same steps like above have discussed with us. It must be necessary to quqlify the state umpiring exam. we will proceed ahead. Our state recommended to BCCI (Board for control of cricket in india). should be cleared with not less then 90% of marks from 100% marks.I was cleared and now a days preparing for PANEL -1 of BCCI umpiring exams....... I must say you guided to all bodies nicely impressionable nice......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an umpire for cricket you are responsible for the calling of many intricate rules of the game. Cricket is a sport that is played around the world, in several different countries. Each country or territory may have different sets of training processes to become an accredited official.

**Instructions
Difficulty: Moderately Easy**
Steps

1. OneTake the Introduction to Umpire course. This course is named differently in other areas of the world. It is offered for those who would like to umpire the occasional cricket games for fun. Moms, dads and teachers are perfect audience for this course.
2. Learn more about the game by attending the GL6 course. This course
   will cover the rules for one-day games and matches. This is a
   starting point for all umpires. Those who pass this class and wish
   to move on with the training can continue from this point. You are
   also able to gain experience at this level by umpiring low-level
   games.
3. Take the exam in GL6 and move on to the GL5 training course. This
   course delves deeper into the 42 rules of the game. You also must
   pass this exam to become an accredited cricket umpire.
4. Practice your hand movements while in the classes and by umpiring
   games. Spectators that are out of earshot expect to see the umpire's
   hand movements while making a call. This is how they can interpret
   what is going on in the game. Movements should be precise and
   correct for each call made.
5. Attend games and matches of varying degrees of difficulty while
   attending classes to become a cricket umpire. These will help you
   see how others umpire do the job. This experience will also give you
   pointers on what to do and not do while out on the field.
6. Join an association of cricket umpires in your area and as your
   reputation grows you can join worldwide associations. It takes years
   to become noticed and requested, but several matches and tournaments
   hire certain associations for their games, and being affiliated with
   them may get you the job.

**As per an Indian Newspaper**

To become an umpire, you have to qualify theory exams conducted by state sports bodies like the Delhi and District Cricket Association (DDCA). Once you qualify, you become eligible for the exams conducted by the Board of Control for Cricket in India (BCCI), and your state cricket association will endorse your candidature.

Please note, gathering information on the exam dates etc becomes easier if you are a cricket player at the state or club level. One should also ideally keep in touch with the state cricket associations’ convening committee to stay updated on exams.

It has also quoted some other aspects as follows

**Skills**
. You must know the 42 laws of cricket properly
. Incisive understanding of the game
. Ability to take spontaneous decisions
. Be a good manager
. Be very patient. You can’t afford to lose your temper at any cost

**How do I get there?**
You have to qualify the theory and practical exams conducted from time to time by state sports bodies. You then become eligible for the exams conducted by the Board of Control for Cricket in India (BCCI) at two levels — one and two. After clearing the second level, you make it to the BCCI panel and can umpire at the highest level. After your case is endorsed by the BCCI for the International Cricket Council (ICC), you can join the race to be an international umpire. But until you pass these exams, you must grab whatever opportunity comes your way to umpire — corporate match, domestic or club level

**Institutes**

There is no institute which trains you to become an umpire. It’s only the BCCI which conducts classes before the umpire’s exam. Once nominated by your state to the BCCI, you can attend these classes

**More at [this link](http://www.hindustantimes.com/education/want-to-be-an-umpire/story-wffj17QokguZAjlsSaoUwM.html)**

Answer (score 3):

Domestically, you start at the club level and work your way through the ranks.  That's not different from any other sport, really.  Details will vary by country, of course.

ICC full members nominate umpires to the International Panel of ICC Umpires, which stands mainly in ODIs.  The best umpires are invited by the ICC to the Elite Panel, which stands mainly in Tests.  So once you are the best umpire in your country, chances are you'll be asked to umpire international matches.