# what is procedure to become a cricket umpire in state level?

Tags: cricket, officiating

I want to know what's the procedure to become a state level Cricket Umpire?

please explain starting from the grass root Steps.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2611/540) this may help you.

Comment: Voted to reopen to close it as a duplicate of the question I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

You need to contact your local cricket authority - I think you can find them at http://www.orissacricket.org/

The normal procedure is to do a preliminary training course, and pass an exam, all on the laws of the game and practices of umpiring. Then you start umpiring in matches (lower-league adult games or childrens' games). If you're good enough, and prepared to put in the time and effort, you will progress through the ranks.

Good luck with it - umpiring is very enjoyable and a great way to be involved in the game at any level.