# How much are Cricket Umpires paid in India starting from Club level to Ranji, Duleep trophy, etc.?

Tags: cricket, officiating

**EDIT**: The question [What is the procedure to become a Cricket Umpire?](http://What%20is%20the%20procedure%20to%20become%20a%20Cricket%20Umpire?) does not answer my question. It does not address the TIME required for an umpire required to reach national level from local level.

Specifically, after officiating local matches, how much time does a state association take to send one's name to BCCI for level 1 exam?

Adding to the question, also how much time does it take for one to reach Ranji level from club level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the procedure to become a Cricket Umpire?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/what-is-the-procedure-to-become-a-cricket-umpire)

Comment: @PhilipKendall its not a duplicate, I've edited the question. Please can you remove the duplicate mark?

Comment: I still think it's a duplicate. Time required is entirely personal and depends on how good an umpire you are. By the simple law of numbers, most club umpires don't make it to national level at all.

Comment: The question is limiting only to India and state associations in India, so its not entirely personal.

Comment: I'm with Philip here, I'm afraid - there is no formula of time for progression in umpiring. You need to gain the qualifications and then the experience, and the timeline for both is completely dependent on the individual.

Answer (score 0):

Found an article [here](https://cricket.yahoo.com/news/bcci-registers-umpires-and-hikes-their-fee.html) regarding salaries of cricket umpires in India. However, this was in 2012, so not sure if salaries have been changed since. The article mentions the following for local(non-international) matches:

- The umpires who are a part of ICC's International Panel and BCCI's Elite Panel receive ₹20,000 per day of the match.
- The other umpires registered under BCCI receive ₹15,000 per day of the match.

Apart from this, all umpires receive ₹750 as daily allowance, ₹600 as conveyance allowance, and free hotel accommodation.

To see the salaries of umpires part of the ICC International Panel see [this article](http://www.totalsportek.com/cricket/icc-umpires-salaries/).